# Left Join con multiples tablas usando expresion lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

tengo tres tablas
AspNetUsers , AspNetRoles y AspNetUserRoles

Como puedo pasar esta consulta sql en expression lambda usando entityframewoek

```
select AspNetUsers.UserName, AspNetRoles.Name from AspNetUsers left join AspNetUserRoles on AspNetUsers.Id = AspNetUserRoles.UserId 
  left join AspNetRoles on AspNetRoles.Id = AspNetUserRoles.RoleId
```

obtengo este resultado

| UserName | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Gerardo | TESTER |
| OScar | TESTER |
| Martin | TESTER |
| Mendoza | TESTER |
| testerAdmin | Admin |

intente de esta manera

```
  var resultUserStorage = _context.UserRoles.AsEnumerable().Join(_context.Roles,
                        x => x.UserId,
                        yy => yy.Id,
                        (x, yy) => new UserPaginationDto() {
                            RolUser = x.UserId,
                            UserId = yy.Id
                        }
                    ).Join(_context.Users,
                        rolesD => rolesD.UserId,
                        userId => userId.Id,
                        (rolesD, userId) => new UserPaginationDto() {
                            UserName = userId.UserName
                        }).ToList();
```

pero obtengo un error

"error": "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."

Comment: Lo que te voy a preguntar no tiene nada que ver con tu error, es solo aclararme, estas seguro que tienes que usar un loft join, no será un inner join?

Comment: Y mas alla de lo que preguntan arriba, tu error no tiene nada pero nada que ver con ese codigo. El sistema se esta quejando que tenes un datareader abierto... si lo cerras, el error desaparece....

Comment: @Japv no hay ningun problema en que sea inner join, me trae los resultados que espero, estoy usando netcore @gbianchi♦ y lo unico que hago es, esa consulta y lo retorno

Comment: @Daniel, debes entender las diferencias entre left join e inner join, se parecen pero no hacen lo mismo, a mi me parece que en tu caso sería mejor un inner join , pero eso lo decides tu

Comment: @Japv en sql es un ejemplo al resultado que espero obtener usando entity, no voy hacer una stored o algo parecido en sql, solo busco , pasar la consulta que muestro de ejemplo en sql a entityframework usando expresion lambda

Comment: Lo que te trato de decir es que tanto en sql como en entity el left join y el inner join arrojan resultados diferentes, por eso tienes que estar claro en lo que quieres

Comment: @Japv a lo que veo tu respuesta se esta saliendo de contexto, si hablas de hacerlo esta manera, `var v = from r in Ramas join k in Kris`, esto se sale de contexto a lo que estoy preguntando, lo que muestro en sql, es un simple ejemplo del resultado que quiero mostrar usando lambda, gracias, ya pude resolver mi pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo mismo respondo mi pregunta, si hay alguna mejora , con gusto recibo una correcion

```
   var resultUserStorage = await _context.UserRoles.Join(_context.Roles,
          x => x.RoleId,
          rolId => rolId.Id,
          (x, rolId) => new
          {
              IdRol = x.UserId,
              NameRol = rolId.Name
          }).Join(_context.Users,
           sf => sf.IdRol,
           zp => zp.Id,
           (sf, zp) => new UserPaginationDto() {
               UserName = zp.UserName,
               RolUser = sf.NameRol
           }
    
          ).ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```